# Challenges with nested dom-repeat & object/array combo

Tags: polymer

I’m having some trouble manipulating an object/array combination & getting the changes to reflect in a nested dom-repeat. It’s working but feels like a hacky approach - can anyone tell me if there’s a better way?

http://jsbin.com/dijogo/edit?html,output  (Chrome only)

See the itemTap function for the specific area of hackiness. Or maybe there’s a better way to go about it generally?

Comment: Are you initially setting the value to an empty array and then back to the original array (which has been updated) just to force the dom-repeat to redraw? If so, I think you're having [the same problem as me here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079535/bindings-when-elements-are-bound-to-same-object-in-memory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this

```
  itemTap: function(e) {
    e.model.set('i.container.value', e.model.i.container.value + ' tapped');
  },
```

Instead of

```
  itemTap: function(e) {
    //This is an overly complicated way to update a "container.value" in the items object arrays no?!

    e.model.set('i.container.value', e.model.i.container.value + ' tapped');

    var array = this.items[e.model.cat];
    array[e.model.index].container.value += ' tapped';

    this.set(['items', e.model.cat], []);
    this.async(function(){this.set(['items', e.model.cat], array);});
  },
```

Fwiw, you can also do

```
    this.items = {
      'One':  [{container:{value: '1a'}}, {container:{value: '1b'}}],
      'Two':  [{container:{value: '2a'}}, {container:{value: '2b'}}],
      'Three':[{container:{value: '3a'}}, {container:{value: '3b'}}]
     });
```

instead of

```
    this.set(['items', 'One'], [{container:{value:'1a'}}, {container:{value:'1b'}}]);
    this.set(['items', 'Two'], [{container:{value:'2a'}}, {container:{value:'2b'}}]);
    this.set(['items', 'Three'], [{container:{value:'3a'}}, {container:{value:'3b'}}]);
```

same with

```
   this.categories = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
```

Comment: Thx! I could swear I tried that - definitely working now though :) Other points are good to know too.