# Bindings when elements are bound to same object in memory

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a situation where I have multiple elements which are bound to the same path and thus the same JS object underneath. Because of this, changes to the object at one place are immediately visible by the other element (though it doesn't know it). The documentation says I need to manually alert the system about this or use a automatic binding, which I am. So a `notifyPath` call is happening.

In the `notifyPath` DOM traversal it eventually nears the element which should react to the change, however the `notifyPath` code does [a check to see if the element already knows about the change](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/master/src/standard/notify-path.html#L82). In my case, because they are both pointing to the same JS object the `old` value is already the `new` value because they're literally the same object in memory. This stops the propagation of the change.

I've [submitted this issue as a potential problem](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1967) but curious about ways around it in the meantime.

Here is a JSBin of the issue: http://jsbin.com/hemexifami/2/edit?html,output

This seems like this kind of thing would be a common case. I've tried manually `notifyPath`-ing in the console directly on the element, passing it the array, however the code just sees that `old` is `new` (since they are both the same JavaScript Array and so it doesn't actually do anything. The documentation says it should return an indication of this but it actually doesn't. See my bug about that [here](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1966).

Have any of you fought this before? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polymer doesn't observe Object references per se, instead, for performance, it tracks changes to objects based on *how you name them* and *how they relate to each other in the tree*.

The section here in the dev guide discusses how to use the `array-selector` element to coordinate between selections in arrays and object bindings:

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#array-selector

If we add an `array-selector` element that knows about `card.sections` it will produce a bindable version of `currentSection` for you.

```
<array-selector id="selector" items="{{card.sections}}" selected="{{currentSection}}"></array-selector>
```

We also add a bit of code to tell the selector which item to select when the index changes:

```
    observers: [
      '_selectSection(card.sections, currentSectionIndex)'
    ],

    _selectSection(sections, index) {
      this.$.sectionSelector.select(sections[index]);
    }
```

Here is a modification of your jsbin using array-selector: http://jsbin.com/qidehe/edit?html,output

Comment: I've updated the code snippets to use real names. Does this help any?

Comment: No, the actual names are irrelevant, except in how they are used to relate objects to each other. When I say "how you name them" it means that `{{object}}` and `{{object.foo}}` are related by the name `object`. You cannot have `{{object}}` and `{{bar.foo}}` and expect them to be related if `object` and `foo` are the same object. Polymer is matching up the names.

Comment: I understand that and originally I was using that format. The problem is that if you do a `notifyPath("object.foo", this.object.foo)`, when it arrives at the other element it does a check to see if the new value is different from the old value. Because they are the same object old and new are always the same and thus propagation stops.

Comment: Yes, and this dirty checking is fundamental to proper function of Polymer. Without a better understanding of what you are trying to do, it's hard to help. Suggest you make a live JSBin that demonstrates a problem.

Comment: I've added a [JSBin link](http://jsbin.com/duxeyemajo/1/edit?html,output) to the Question

Comment: I'm not sure why the JSBin link was a much older revision. I had to redo it from memory but [here is a working version](http://jsbin.com/hemexifami/2/edit?html,output)